# How do I add a value to an Input Field on the click of a button?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I have built a calculator as a project in P5JS, however how can I code it so that when I click the plus/subtract/divide or multiply button, it will add a value to the input field so when I click the plus button, it will add + to the input field, but I do not want it to replace any value already in the input field so if I type 45, then when I click the plus button, it will shows 45 + . My code is below, how can add this feature to the function PLUSX?

```
  function setup() {
  createCanvas(850, 800);

    ROOTX= createButton("√");                //  Create Button
    ROOTX.position(380, 260);
    ROOTX.size(80, 30);
    ROOTX.mousePressed(SquareRoot);          //send to function SquareRoot
    
    SQUAREX= createButton("x²");             //  Create Button
    SQUAREX.position(380, 300);
    SQUAREX.size(80, 30);
    SQUAREX.mousePressed(Square);            //send to function Square
    
    PISYMBOLX= createButton("π");            //  Create Button
    PISYMBOLX.position(380, 340);
    PISYMBOLX.size(80, 30);
    PISYMBOLX.mousePressed(PISYMBOL);        // send to function PISYMBOL
    
    PERCENTAGEX= createButton("%");          //  Create Button
    PERCENTAGEX.position(380, 380);
    PERCENTAGEX.size(80, 30);
    PERCENTAGEX.mousePressed(PROMPT);        // sen to function Prompt
    
    INPUT = createInput();                   //  Create Input
    INPUT.position(270, 200);
    INPUT.size(300);
    
    
   createInput = ('<input id="userInput1" value="0">') 
    
    NUMEQUALX = createButton('=');                   //  Create Input
    NUMEQUALX.position(270, 460);
    NUMEQUALX.size(300)
    NUMEQUALX.mousePressed(answer);        //send to function answer
       
    //Basic Math Operation
    
    PLUS = createButton("+");                //  Create Button
    PLUS.position(270, 260);
    PLUS.size(80, 30);
    PLUS.mousePressed(PLUSX);   
                //send 
                  
    MINUS = createButton("-");                //  Create Button
    MINUS.position(270, 300);
    MINUS.size(80, 30);
    MINUS.mousePressed();          //send 

    DIVIDE = createButton("×");                //  Create Button
    DIVIDE.position(270, 340);
    DIVIDE.size(80, 30);
    DIVIDE.mousePressed();          //send 

    MULTIPLY = createButton("÷");                //  Create Button
    MULTIPLY.position(270, 380);
    MULTIPLY.size(80, 30);
    MULTIPLY.mousePressed();  
  
    CUSTOMsquare = createButton("x❏");                //  Create Button
    CUSTOMsquare.position(500, 300);
    CUSTOMsquare.size(80, 30);
    CUSTOMsquare.mousePressed(CSP);        // sen to function Prompt
    
    }

var Percent;                //declare variable
var ROOTX;                 //declare variable  
var SQUAREX;              //declare variable
var PISYMBOLX;           //declare variable
var PERCENTAGEX;        //declare variable
var INPUT;             //declare variable
var NUMEQUALX;        //declare variable
var Key1;           //declare variable
var Key2;          //declare varaible

  

function draw() {
background(255);

    textFont("This is a sans-serif font");            
    text(" Calculator", 10, 40);                
    fill(64, 64, 64);              
    textSize(20);  

              
    text("+    Addition", 735, 20); 
    text("-     Subtract", 735, 40); 
    text("/     Divide"  ,   735, 60); 
    text("*    Multiply", 735, 80); 
    textSize(30);   
    
    }




function CSP() {
}
  
  





function PLUSX()  {



  


} 


function resetx()  {
  
button.mousePressed (setup);
  


}






function SquareRoot() {                      
  
let a = INPUT.value();                        
let x = sqrt(a);
  
  console.log('SQUARE ROOT:' + x); 

}









function Square() {
  
let b = INPUT.value();                         //  INPUT Value
let y = sq(b);

  console.log('SQUARED:' + y); 

}










function PISYMBOL() {        // function PISYMBOL

let c = INPUT.value();   
let z = (c)*3.141592653589793238;

  console.log(c + ' PI: ' ); 
  console.log(z);
  
}







function answer()         {
      
let x = INPUT.value();
console.log(x);
console.log('ANSWER:');
 console.log(eval(x));  
  
  //text('ANSWER:' + ANW, 85, 600);
    
  
 
    
  
}


 

//console.log(eval(ANS));
    //console.log(eval(ANS));
    


function PROMPT()  {
  
ANS = INPUT.value();     
 
{
  
                              
times = window.prompt('Find percentage of what value?');                      
    
percentD  = times / 100
percent =  percentD * INPUT.value();
  console.log(ANS + '% OF' + times);
  console.log( percent);                             
}
  
}
```

Comment: `inputfield.value += new_character`

Comment: it is not working  i typed under function PLUSX this: 
INPUT.value += ('+');

Comment: Don't do `createInput = ('<input id="userInput1" value="0">')`. That's redefining the `createInput` function from P5.

Comment: I don't think the value returned by `createInput()` is the `<input>` element, it's a P5 object. You'll need to use the P5 methods, which I'm not familiar with.

Comment: i deleted that part you said not to do and now in function PLUSX I added   INPUT.value += ('+'); and still nothing happens?

Comment: If you try to make a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) You might find out yourself. Usually is good to isolate stuff in a new code so you grasp how to use that piece out of the 'bigger' problem. I usually do that in the [editor.p5js.org](https://editor.p5js.org)